# LuaInterface & .NET- LuaAPI Failure: L->top < L->ci->top

Tags: c#, .net, lua, luainterface

I am struggling with the below error when trying to set a global in a LuaInterface Lua VM instance from .NET.

```
LuaAPI failure: L->top < L->ci->top, file 'h:\dev\vastpark\~repositories\public\trunk
\components\luainterface\lua-5.1.2\src\lapi.c', line 227
```

I am assigning the global as below:

```
_LuaVM[globalName] = value;
```

Any info on the error would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: you probably want to post some code that runs before that assignment. it looks like that error is related to improper stack clean up.